# Why is "sesame" not pronounced as "se" and "same"?

Tags: pronunciation

The word "sesame" is pronounced as "se" "suh" "mee", with 3 syllables.  Why is it not pronounced as "se" "same", with 2 syllables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pronunciation is derived from the French original term which entered Middle English at the beginning of the 15th century:

> 1425; ***[Middle English sisamie](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sesame), from Middle French sisame***, learned borrowing from Latin sīsamum, variant of sēsama, from Ancient Greek σήσαμον (sḗsamon, “sesame seed”),

(Wiktionary)

Answer (score 0):

Due to its origin :

According to Oxford , [sesame](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sesame)

> Late Middle English: via Latin from Greek sēsamon, sēsamē; compare with Arabic simsim.